# Contruct a datetime with specific format

Tags: php

i have a date string from my db, the date is `16/11/2010` and its format is `d/m/Y`, i want to modify its like this.

```
<?php
   $date_from_db= '16/11/2010'; // format is d/m/Y
   $date = new DateTime($date_from_db);
   $date-> modify('+1 week');
   echo $date-> format('d/m/Y') ;
?>
```

i have got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/11/2012) at position 0 (1).
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_from_db);`

Comment: @N.B.: You should have posted this as an answer.

Comment: That error tells us that this is not your real testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not one of the time formats supported by DateTime class constructor.

This page shows valid formats

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

You should use an actual SQL-compliant date field (typically YYYY-MM-DD) in your DB.  Or if you can't change the way your are storing the dates, use `DateTime::CreateFromFormat` as suggested in other answer.

I would highly suggest using a more standard storage format though.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 $date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d-m-y", "16-11-2010");
```

Comment: @N.B : thx for reply, when i try to display it like this `echo $date;` i cant see anything, and i have try like this `echo $date->format('d/m/Y')` i got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object".